# Large performance penalty when compiling in container

Tags: linux, docker, kernel, c++

### Summary

When building a large C/C++-based code base, the build in a Docker container takes about 3.5 times longer than the build in the OS. The issue can be mitigated by declaring all 3rd party includes, provided by the Conan package manager, not to be system includes. The question is if the containerized build time can be reduced any other way.

### Setup

Build server:

- AMD EPYC 7742 dual CPU w/ 512GB memory
- SMT turned off
- Debian sid , kernel 5.18.5-1
- Docker CE, 20.10.14+dfsg1 (server)
- SELinux: off; Apparmor: off; mitigations: off

Build container:

- CentOS 7
- GCC 9.3.1 (devtoolset-9)
- CMake 3.18
- Conan 1.44.1
- Ninja 1.10.0

Container options:

- Privileged: true (tested also with false)
- SecurityOpt: "seccomp=unconfined", "label=disabled"
- ShmSize: 4G
- no resource limitations (all CPUs, all memory)

### Description

I have been investigating a large degradation of build speed when compiling our C/C++-based software in a Docker container.

To establish a base line, I compiled the software directly in the OS. For a sub-project of about 4.5k source files, the build took 170s +/- 0.14% (average over three runs). using all 128 cores. When I compile the same sub-project in the build container, it takes 531s +/- 0.25% to complete. Since the entire additional time is spent in the system, I ran `perf top -g` on one CPU for an entire build. This is what I got:

```
  Children      Self  Shared Object            Symbol
+   81.89%     0.02%  [kernel]                 [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
+   81.81%     0.02%  [kernel]                 [k] do_syscall_64
+   69.87%     0.02%  [kernel]                 [k] vfs_fstatat
+   63.56%     0.06%  [kernel]                 [k] vfs_statx
+   60.76%     0.01%  [kernel]                 [k] __do_sys_newlstat
+   57.43%    57.37%  [kernel]                 [k] avc_lookup
+   54.22%     0.05%  [kernel]                 [k] filename_lookup
+   54.06%     0.03%  [kernel]                 [k] path_lookupat
+   50.17%     0.49%  [kernel]                 [k] link_path_walk.part.0.constprop.0
+   43.15%     0.15%  [kernel]                 [k] inode_permission
+   42.31%     0.05%  [kernel]                 [k] ovl_permission
+   35.90%     0.04%  [kernel]                 [k] override_creds
+   19.00%     0.00%  [unknown]                [k] 0x00007f02abb49505
+   18.99%     0.00%  [unknown]                [k] 0x00007f2f95987505
+   13.59%     2.38%  [kernel]                 [k] revert_creds
+   12.46%    10.66%  [kernel]                 [k] selinux_inode_permission
+    7.63%     0.02%  [kernel]                 [k] complete_walk
+    7.62%     0.26%  [kernel]                 [k] lockref_get_not_dead
+    7.59%     0.02%  [kernel]                 [k] try_to_unlazy
+    7.51%     0.04%  [kernel]                 [k] __legitimize_path
+    6.73%     0.00%  cc1plus                  [.] 0x00000000015f44b6
+    6.56%     0.01%  [kernel]                 [k] do_sys_openat2
+    6.23%     0.01%  [kernel]                 [k] do_filp_open
+    5.49%     0.00%  libc-2.17.so             [.] 0x00007f2e3a46b505
+    5.37%     0.01%  [kernel]                 [k] path_openat
+    5.34%     0.00%  [kernel]                 [k] __x64_sys_open
+    5.05%     0.05%  [kernel]                 [k] getname_flags.part.0
+    4.88%     0.01%  [kernel]                 [k] ovl_getattr
```

The project uses Conan for dependency management, and CMake to configure the build tool, Ninja. All include files provided by Conan packages are declared as system includes:

```
include_directories( SYSTEM ${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

When I run the build, the build timed in the build container are roughly a factor of 3.5 slower than when building it outside. The additional time is spent entirely in the kernel in functions `avc_code` and `selinux_inode_permision`.

The workaround I have found is to configure all includes from the Conan packages to be "not" system includes:

```
set( CMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED ON )
include_directories( ${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

, but that is undesirable in terms of warnings, e.g.

My questions are:

- why is the containerized build slower that much slower?
- is there is anything else I can do to avoid that

Comment: How many cores are used by the container? Why is the ShmSize so small?

Comment: @Ramhound all builds were done with all 128 cores. The container was started without resource limitation. What ShmSize would you recommend? The default is 64M, I increased it to 4G

Comment: Silly question the CentOS 7 docker image is 64-bit, right? Depends on the memory usage during the compilation of your code.  Based on what you provided, while you compiled within Debian, the compiler would have access to 512GB of memory. If you have ruled out that Docker not having access to a certain amount of cores, then the only other (main) reason for the additional time, would be memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The image is 64bit, yes. I am running an unmodified build in the container right now. According to `docker stats`, the build does not seem to use more than ~23GB memory... I will try with a large shm size and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Based on my research `ShmSize` is basically the swap file system, so it should be near the same size as your physical system requires to compile to software, in order to eliminate that as the culprit.

Comment: I varied the shm size from 64MB (default) to 4GB and 64GB. It had no effect on the build time.

Comment: Curious if you made any progress on this. I am looking at a large slowdown on compile times for a large compile project (native OS takes ~25mins on 32 cores, requires ~50G mem) running in conainers. we are seeing 2 - 3x slower